# Why is a function not defined in the .o file for this C++ class?

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I have a C++ class that I'm using, and there's a function in it that's not showing up when I look at the .o file with `nm --demangle', and the function is missing when the program tries to run, even though everything builds fine.

The header looks like:

```
#ifndef __COLLECTION_H
#define __COLLECTION_H

#include <vector>

#include "ObjectInstance.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Collection : public ObjectInstance
{       
protected:
    vector<T*> items;
    void internalInsertAt(T* item, int index);
    void internalRemoveIndex(int index);
    void internalRemoveItem(T* item);

public:
    virtual ~Collection();
    // Specific functions for this interface
    static int item(jsplugin_obj *this_obj, jsplugin_obj *function_obj, int argc, 
    T* internalGetItem(int index);
    int getSize();
    void addItem(T* item);
};

#endif
```

and the addItem function is implemented as

```
template <class T>
void Collection<T>::addItem(T* item)
{   
    items.push_back(item);
}
```

The error I get is from when I try to inherit this class in another one and shows up at runtime: `undefined symbol: _ZN10CollectionIN4NJSE5TrackEE7addItemEPS1_`

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, but can't tell what it is.

Comment: Have you actually specified the library when linking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler needs to have access to the entire template definition (not just the signature) of `addItem` in order to generate code for each instantiation of the template, so you need to move its definition to your header i.e follow the [inclusion model](http://books.google.com/books?id=EotSAwuBkJoC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=Inclusion+model+in+templates&source=bl&ots=iwO-H5_f8b&sig=_lQy9I36pfxWuU5iIw1IDCw-uK0&hl=en&ei=guCOTMbqGJHyvQPzs9DUCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Inclusion%20model%20in%20templates&f=false).

Infact modern C++ compilers do not easily support the separate compilation model for templates.

Comment: Great link. Section 6.1.1, titled "Linker Errors", goes over the exact problem the OP is complaining about.

Comment: The canonical newbie's reference is C++ FAQ item [35.12 Why can't I separate the definition of my templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12), + the following items.

Comment: @Alf : Hmm right. I should have given that link too in addition to [C++ Templates'](http://books.google.com/books?id=EotSAwuBkJoC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=Inclusion+model+in+templates&source=bl&ots=iwO-H5_f8b&sig=_lQy9I36pfxWuU5iIw1IDCw-uK0&hl=en&ei=guCOTMbqGJHyvQPzs9DUCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Inclusion%20model%20in%20templates&f=false) link.

Answer (score 3):

Is the function in a header file or source file?  The simplest way to deal with templates is to put *all* template definitions in header files, to guarantee the definition is available to whatever code instantiates it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think that's because the function is a member of a template. In C++ you can't compile templates (at least not easily). If you want to distribute template classes, write all the code in the header.

Answer (score 2):

Templates in separate compilation units can be a nightmare, and requires serious compiler heavy-lifting.

Remember that specific versions of your template function must be compiled for each type T that you attempt to instantiate the template for.

For this reason, the easiest way is to place all your template function definitions into the '.h' header file.